# How do you keep simulation bake data in different scenes?

Tags: physics, baking, cloth-simulation, scene

I have a cloth simulation that I want to render in Eevee to achieve a certain NPR look, but also render a shadow on a shadow-catcher in Cycles.

I've done this kind of thing in the past without any simulations, just straight keyframe animation and I do it by copying the scene either linked or not, and then putting the output back together in Compositor.

But when I try to do it with the simulation, the bake data doesn't go into the new copied scene.
I've tried to pin the object from the original scene with no luck, the bake data shows but has no effect on the mesh.

I've tried to convert the simulation to ShapeKeys by exporting as an .mmd and reimporting, but that opened up a whole other can of headaches.

Can baked data be shared over multiple scenes?

Blender 2.82a
OS X 10.13 High Sierra

Comment: Have you tried rendering? I had the same problem with parenting, didn't work in VP, looked fine in render. However you don't need scenes for shadow catchers, use Render Layers. If you need more details on that, let me know.

Comment: Yes, I have rendered. And again, to achieve the look I want, I have to have separate outputs. I can't switch render engines in render layers and render them at the same time.  I was trying to keep my question simple, but I'm also getting motion blur from another scene as well. All 3 scenes need to have the simulation run exactly the same.

Comment: Ups, didn't see Eevee in there, sorry. However, not 100% sure if this is your issue, but Brecht suggests this: https://developer.blender.org/T36382
There's a way to link baked data between files, but tbh I didn't get it to work: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/baking.html
I tried 2 linked scenes with dynamic hair simulation, with both disk cache and library path enabled, that worked.